# Как изменить внешний вид курсора по умолчанию через CSS?

Tags: css

Нужно заменить стандартный курсор при наведении на блок на картинку (размеры картинки 144*270). Делаю следующим образом https://jsfiddle.net/sjsn8ckk/, но ничего не работает не в одном браузере (картинку подключил для примера). Также пробовал подключать вместо картинки сконвертированный файл cursor.cur, но все равно не работает.

```
<div id="block"></div>

#block {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #000;
  cursor: url(cursor.png), auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Картинка должна быть в формате .ico

```
  cursor: url(http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico), default !important;
```

- https://jsfiddle.net/sjsn8ckk/5/

Comment: Странно, нигде не видел .ico.

Comment: Internet Explorer - CUR и ANI;
Firefox, Chrome, Safari - CUR, PNG, GIF, JPG;

Comment: Не обязательно. Тут скорее дело в размерах, в примере автора вопроса, изображение имеет размеры 512x807, когда как максимально возможные 128x128, а для наибольшей совместимости рекомендуется ограничиться размерами 32x32. [Using URL values for the cursor property](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_User_Interface/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property) раздел **Limitations**.

Comment: По размерам понял, спасибо. Должно ли изображение быть пропорциональным? Или может иметь разные размеры сторон?

Comment: @АнтонПетренко не могу сказать, экспериментируйте, в крайнем случае всегда можно подогнать изображение под формат 1:1, оставив пустые прозрачные области.

Comment: с gif тоже работает http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/kXVGZz?editors=110

Comment: В IE с gif не работает.

Comment: А почему в примере с ICO размер иконки 32*32, а в IE она уменьшена?