# Как изменить курсор?

Tags: html, css

Как можно изменить курсор в `html` документе и поставить собственный курсор?

Comment: Курсоры бывают разные, какой имеется в виду?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor

Comment: Jora Sahakyan, конкретизируйте, пожалуйста, что Вы хотите изменить: [**caret**](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/t/textcurs.htm) или [**mouse pointer**](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/m/mouspoin.htm)? Оба элемента называют «курсором». Спасибо.

Comment: я хочу поставить собственный курсор,выбранным мной картинкой.почти все  варианты пробовал не работает

Comment: mouse pointer хочу изменить

Comment: Можно [**так**](http://jsfiddle.net/q94EV/). Спасибо.

Comment: https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/seo-and-web-icons-1/512/target-512.png с этой картинкой не работает :(

Comment: @JoraSahakyan  для картинок для cursor есть ограничения - размер должен быть маленький

Comment: @МаксимЛенский body, html {
    cursor: url("https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/seo-and-web-icons-1/512/target-512.png"), auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

Comment: @МаксимЛенский почему так не работает?

Comment: @JoraSahakyan  потому что картинка большая

Comment: @МаксимЛенский каким должен быть размер?

Comment: @МаксимЛенский все! сработал спасибо ;)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как изменить внешний вид курсора по умолчанию через CSS?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/555205/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4-%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-css)

Answer (score 4):

Вот так это делается

```css
.cur{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background:red;
 cursor: url("https://png.icons8.com/dusk/2x/cursor.png"), auto;
}
.cur1{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background:blue;
 cursor: url("https://png.icons8.com/nolan/2x/hand-cursor.png"), auto; 
}
```

```html
<div class="cur"></div>
<div class="cur1"></div>
```